# Is norm of $L_p$ functions can be attained by some duality functions? Why?

Tags: real-analysis

$1\leq p \leq \infty$, $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ restricted on the unit sphere $S^{d-1}$, then there exists $g\in L^q(S^{d-1})$ such that $\|g\|_{q}=1$ and $$\|f\|_p=\int_{S^{d-1}}f(y)g(y)d\sigma(y)$$

Where $d\sigma(y)$ is the spherical measure and $\|\|_p $ is the norm of the space $L_p(S^{d-1})$

I know $$\|f\|_p= \sup_{\|g\|_q=1}\int f(y)g(y)d\sigma(y)$$  But how to prove the existence of $g$ that attains the supremum? Is that true for every $L_p(S^{d-1})$ function? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

Let $V=\langle f \rangle$ be the subspace spawned by $f$. Let $\varphi\in V^*$ given by $\varphi(\alpha f) = \alpha ||f||_p$.

By Hahn-Banach, there exists an extension $\hat{\varphi}\in L_p(S^{d-1})^*$ such that $||\hat{\varphi}||=1$ and $\hat{\varphi}(f)=||f||_p $.

But, by Riez representation theorem, there exists $g\in L_q(S^{d-1})=L_p(S^{d-1})^*$ such that $||g||_q= ||\hat{\varphi}|| = 1$ and
$$||f||_p = \hat{\varphi}(f) =\int fgd\sigma .$$